# Creating dynamic div content with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm looking to put a div on my website where the content changes based on what link is `clicked` without refreshing. The content to put there comes from a `MySQL database` and it's put in JSON.
My problem is that I can't get the JSON data to display when clicking the links.

Here's the script I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.getJSON("jsondata.php",rightSideData);
   function rightSideData(data) {
      for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++) {
         $("#changetext"+data[i].id).click(function() {
            $("#rightside").html("<h1>" + data[i].title + "</h1><p />" + data[i].content);
         });
      }
   }
});
```

This is the `div` element that has to change:

```
<div class='rightside' id='rightside'>Test</div>
```

The links are constructed this way:

```
echo "<a id='changetext" . $row['id'] . "'> ";
echo "<div class='tile'>";
echo "<h2>Tile</h2></div></a>";
```

I've tested the different elements and they work fine *(changing the divs content with hardcoded data, displaying the JSON data)*, but I'm having a hard time figuring out why the combined thing isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects does'nt have a length, use `$.each` to iterate it instead, unless it's actually an array containing objects :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.getJSON("jsondata.php",rightSideData);

   function rightSideData(data) {
      $.each(data, function(i, d) {
         $("#changetext" + d.id).on('click', function() {
             var h1 = $('<h1 />', {text : d.title}),
                 p  = $('<p />', {text : d.content});
             $("#rightside").html(h1.add(p));
         });
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: Whilst your updated code is clearer, but it displays only the title. With me being so new to this I can't seem to find the mistake...

Comment: @Freezzo - That's my bad, with most jQuery methods you can add multiple elements, like `.append(elem1, elem2, elem3)`, but `html()` only accepts one element it seems, so we have to add the two elements together to create one element, edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `i` var  will be `data.length` at the end of the loop and that's what the click handler will see.